# Looping over Values in Tensor and count until value changes

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

My dataset looks like this:

```
**user_id** 

0   38094   
1   38094   
2   8937    
3   126440
4   126440


WANTED EXAMPLE-OUTPUT: 2,1,2 (because line 0 and 1 are identical -> 2 (...))
```

I need a loop that goes over this and prints how many rows are identical (sequentially). I dont know if there's any Tensorflow operation but that would help alot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible using [`tf.unique_with_counts`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/unique_with_counts)

In your case:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

input_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor([38094, 38094, 8937, 126440, 126440])

_, _, output_tensor = tf.unique_with_counts(input_tensor)
print(output_tensor)
```

This code will output

> tf.Tensor([2 1 2], shape=(3,), dtype=int32)